# How to Save and Load Machine Learning (One-vs-Rest) Models?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

My code loops through each label or category then creates a model out of it. However, what I want is to create a general model that will be able to accept new predictions that are inputs from a user.

I'm aware that the code below saves the model that is fit for the last category in the loop. How can I fix this so that models for each category will be saved so that when I load those models, i would be able to predict a label for a new text?

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(strip_accents='unicode', 
stop_words=stop_words, analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,3), norm='l2')
vectorizer.fit(train_text)
vectorizer.fit(test_text)

x_train = vectorizer.transform(train_text)
y_train = train.drop(labels = ['question_body'], axis=1)

x_test = vectorizer.transform(test_text)
y_test = test.drop(labels = ['question_body'], axis=1)

# Using pipeline for applying linearSVC and one vs rest classifier
SVC_pipeline = Pipeline([
                ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(), n_jobs=1)),
            ])
for category in categories:
    print('... Processing {}'.format(category))

    # train the SVC model using X_dtm & y
    SVC_pipeline.fit(x_train, train[category])
    # compute the testing accuracy of SVC
    svc_prediction = SVC_pipeline.predict(x_test)
    print("SVC Prediction:")
    print(svc_prediction)
    print('Test accuracy is {}'.format(f1_score(test[category], svc_prediction)))
    print("\n")

#save the model to disk
filename = 'svc_model.sav'
pickle.dump(SVC_pipeline, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes in your code.

1. You are fitting your `TfidfVectorizer` on both train and test:

   ```
   vectorizer.fit(train_text)
   vectorizer.fit(test_text)
   ```

   This is wrong. Calling `fit()` is not incremental. It will not learn on both data if called two times. The most recent call to `fit()` will forget everything from past calls. You never fit (learn) something on test data.

   What you need to do is this:

   ```
   vectorizer.fit(train_text)
   ```
2. The pipeline does not work the way you think:

   ```
   # Using pipeline for applying linearSVC and one vs rest classifier
   SVC_pipeline = Pipeline([
                            ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(), n_jobs=1)),
                           ])
   ```

   See that you are passing `LinearSVC` inside the `OneVsRestClassifier`, so it will automatically use that without the need of `Pipeline`. `Pipeline` will not do anything here. `Pipeline` is of use when you sequentially want to pass your data through multiple models. Something like this:

   ```
   pipe = Pipeline([
                    ('pca', pca), 
                    ('logistic', LogisticRegression())
                   ])
   ```

   What the above `pipe` will do is pass the data to `PCA` which will transform it. Then that new data is passed to `LogisticRegression` and so on..

   Correct usage of pipeline in your case can be:

   ```
     SVC_pipeline = Pipeline([
                             ('vectorizer', vectorizer)
                             ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(), n_jobs=1)),
                            ])
   ```

   See more examples here:

   - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#examples-using-sklearn-pipeline-pipeline
3. You need to describe more about your `"categories"`. Show some examples of your data. You are not using `y_train` and `y_test` anywhere. Is the categories different from `"question_body"`?

Comment: @CodeGeek Is your problem resolved? I have requested for more information in my point 3.

Comment: Yes, i decided to save the model created in each category :)